# How to migrate:rollback a specific table in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.1, database-migration, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

I know this feature has been already added in **laravel 5.3**, but I am using **Laravel 5.1**, how can I do it using **5.1** version? I've also searched it on internet, but there's only solution for **5.3**. Hope you can help me, and for those who have the same problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just edit the `batch` of your migration, update it as last migration. For example, if the batch of the table is `73` and you already have `74` & `75` you can just **`UPDATE migrations SET batch = 76 WHERE batch = 73`**, now your table's batch is `76`, **RUN** `php artisan migrate:rollback` , and there you go.

Comment: Hahaha Though it is late, it is a great idea! Works perfectly!

Comment: Great answer, i thought i can do that with tinker, but migration classes aren't autoloaded and namespaced.

Comment: Such an idea! Thank you brother

Answer (score 0):

You can't rollback a specific table even in the latest version (5.4) of laravel. You can only rollback a particular migration. This question was asked recently and there a couple of answers which apply to 5.1 as well.

[Rollback a specific migration in laravel5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099885/rollback-a-specific-migration-in-laravel5/44100120)

If you are indeed talking about rolling back a specific migration then do this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30288058/5892849

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44100120/5892849

Comment: Yah indeed men. But it is just for **L5.3** and up. I'm looking for **L5.1** version.